# How to change placeholder value on date widget in django-filter?

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

Finally managed to get my table filters working using django-filter. As a final piece of eye-candy I want to set the initial value of the date widget in my filter to show epoch-date (1970-01-01).

I've followed the documentation but no luck.

```
class LineItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    user = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(empty_label="User", field_name='journal_entry__user', queryset=User.objects.all())
    TYPE0_CHOICES = list(journal.models.JOURNALENRTY_TYPE_CHOICES)
    type0 = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(field_name='journal_entry__type', choices=TYPE0_CHOICES, empty_label="Type")
    date_from = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateTypeInput(attrs={'placeholder': '1970-01-01'}), field_name='journal_entry__date', lookup_expr='gte', label='From') <!-- Epoch data set here but not showing -->
    date_to = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateTypeInput(), field_name='journal_entry__date', lookup_expr='lte', label='To')
    ledger = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(empty_label="Ledger", queryset=Ledger.objects.all())
    project = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(empty_label="Project", queryset=Project.objects.all())
```

Note that my data widget is defined in forms.py:

```
class DateTypeInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

This is what my table looks like. I've enabled sortable columns, filters, and pagination, and it's working lovely :)
[image: Bootstrap table with filters]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so figured it out. Was using wrong attribute. It needs to be value and not placeholder. All works now:

```
date_from = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateTypeInput(attrs={'value': '1970-01-01'}), field_name='journal_entry__date', lookup_expr='gte', label='From')
```